# Regex extract number from a string with a specific pattern in Alteryx

Tags: regex, alteryx

I have string like this which looks like a url

```
mainpath/path2/abc/PI 6/j
```

From the string I need to get the number along with **PI**

Main problem is the position of **PI** part wont be always the same. Sometimes it could be at the end. Sometimes at the middle.

So how can I get that number extracted using regex?
I'm really stucked with this

Comment: Is `PI` always `PI`? Or it can be any string? Is there always a space? Are there other characters in between? Or before? Or after?

Comment: It will be always PI, But in different positions of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as using the [RegEx Tool](https://help.alteryx.com/2019.3/RegEx.htm). A Regular Expression of `/PI (\d+)` and the Output Method of "Parse" should do the trick.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Alteryx... suppose your field name is `[s]` and you're looking for `[f]` (in your example the value of `[f]` is "PI")... then you could have a Formula tool that first finds *`/PI`* by first creating a new field `[tmp]` as:

```
SubString([s],FindString([s],"/"+[f])+1)
```

and then creating the field you're after `[target]`:

```
SubString([tmp],0,FindString([tmp],"/"))
```

From there run `[target]` through a "Text to Columns" tool to split on the space, which will give you "PI" and "6".